# concatenate and if formula in excel

Tags: excel-2010, concatenation

I want to use concatenate to merge these addresses but when the "block #" is empty concatenate automatically not include it in result of formula. Is it possible? if yes than how?
Kindly help I am really thankful to you.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8uYoL.png)

Comment: your question is not clear, If you select empty cell it must be show in formula bar and no change in result because cell is empty.

Answer (score 1):

An Easy way to concantinate things would be to use operator & for a row and
then use fill command.
With use of **If** and **ISBLANK** function we can achive that I think.

```
=IF(ISBLANK(B2),B1 & " " & B3, B1 & " "& B2 & " " & B3)
```

---

**Usage of If**

DESCRIPTION

The Microsoft Excel IF function returns one value if the condition is TRUE, or another value if the condition is FALSE.

SYNTAX

The syntax for the IF function in Microsoft Excel is:

```
IF( condition, [value_if_true], [value_if_false] )
```

Parameters or Arguments

1.condition :
  The value that you want to test.

2.value_if_true
  Optional. It is the value that is returned if condition evaluates to TRUE.

3.value_if_false 
  Optional. It is the value that is return if condition evaluates to FALSE.

---

**Usage of Isblank**

DESCRIPTION

The Microsoft Excel ISBLANK function can be used to check for blank or null values.

SYNTAX

The syntax for the ISBLANK function in Microsoft Excel is:

```
ISBLANK( value )
```

Parameters or Arguments

value
The value that you want to test. 
If value is blank, this function will return TRUE. If value is not blank, the function will return FALSE.

---

Reference:

**if and isblank():**
http://www.techonthenet.com/excel/formulas/if.php

**Fill Command**
https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Fill-data-automatically-in-worksheet-cells-74e31bdd-d993-45da-aa82-35a236c5b5db

Answer (score 0):

This formula might help assuming House# = ColA & Block# =ColB

```
=A1&B1
```

But still you cant see the space. Instead of space use **n/a** or some other text you may get what you want :)